# Google PageSpeed Insights: Is it really worth chasing top score?

Tags: user-experience, pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

Is it really worth chasing a 100% score on Google PageSpeed Insights at the sacrifice of the best User Experience?

Some of the opportunities suggested create a poorer experience, so is it really worth it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be materially related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

### Is it really worth chasing a 100% score on Google PageSpeed Insights at the sacrifice of the best User Experience?

NEVER sacrifice user experience in the pursuit of speed and performance.

Speed is important but how people interact with your site is far more important, especially if you are spending money driving people to your site.

With that being said your second point is completely false....

### Some of the opportunities suggested create a poorer experience, so is it really worth it?

There is not one suggestion in PSI that will negatively affect user experience.

This shows that either you didn't understand a point or that you have implemented a fix incorrectly. (they are not that well explained to be fair)

**If there are particular points you are struggling with then please post a separate question, I will happily guide you.**

Speed has been proven again and again to improve conversions, with every second being worth around 10% in conversion rate improvement (or every 0.1 second being worth a 1% increase in conversions).

### When to not chase 100% score on PSI

The actually reason to not chase perfection is time and resources, coupled with diminishing returns.

To get a site to 80 / 100 is normally an easy process.

To get from 80 to 90 takes a reasonable amount of work.

To get from 90 to 100 normally means designing the site from the ground up to be lightweight and involves all sorts of tricks such as inlining critical CSS.

Let time and effort guide you, there is no real benefit of trying to push for 100% unless you are turning over a significant amount of money (£1 million+) as the conversion rate increase is not proportional to time spent and cost.

On my site (https://klu.io) I had already designed it to be lightweight from the start and it still took me nearly a day to optimise all the SVGs, set up automatic CSS inlining for critical content etc. etc.

I will be the first to say that extra day effort was not worth it, other than to 'show off' to clients that I can get sites to 100, I never take a client site to that extreme as it does not provide any financial benefit and I would recommend the same to you, **aim for 85 and above** and you will have a high performance website **fit for 99% of needs.**

Comment: I'd also like to note, that the latest shift in PSI to _First Contentful Paint_, _Largest Contentful Paint_ and _Cumulative LAyout Shift_ is a way towards rewarding a good UX.